# numpy - 2d array indexing

Tags: python, indexing, numpy, multidimensional-array

According to [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues) numpy's default behaviour is to index arrays first by rows then by columns:

```
a = numpy.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]

print a[0][1] # is 1
```

I want to index the array using the geometrically oriented-convention `a[x][y]`, as in x-axis and y-axis. How can I change the indexing order without modifying the array's shape so that `a[0][1]` would return 2?

Comment: I borrowed the terminology from the docs (see the link): "Matrix notation uses the first index to indicate which row is being selected and the second index to indicate which column is selected. This is opposite the geometrically oriented-convention for images where people generally think the first index represents x position (i.e., column) and the second represents y position (i.e., row)"

Comment: Nevermind, was thinking something else.

Comment: Just as a note, when indexing multi-dimensional arrays you should use the notation a[i,j] rather than a[i][j]. I find on my machine that the later is 2x slower.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the tip. It looks more readable too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write `a.T[0,1]` to use indices of the transpose of the array, which are the other way around in 2D.

Comment: Does this create a new transposed array each time I access using this notation?

Comment: The `.T` only creates a view of the original array, so you are not copying data. It should be relatively fast.

Comment: Wouln't a.T[0,1] be better, because it would leave out the intermediate array avoiding to call the __getitem__ routine twice?